# Angular filter by array of values

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am trying to filter a list of items using an array of values.  So far I've successfully been  able to filter numerous fields in a table, but I haven't been able to filter using numerous values within one column of the table.  This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FipZ82MkAe4gt1Ic5Grj?p=preview) shows this filter object being used

```
$scope.filters = {
   user:{
     name:"John"
   },
   status:{
     name: "Approved" 
   }
};
```

However, what I am trying to accomplish to generate a filtered list based off this filters object:

```
$scope.filters = {
  user:{
    name:"John"
  },
  status:{
    name: ["Approved", "For Review"] 
  }
};
```

Basically I want a list of all Johns whose status name is either "Approved" or "For Review".

Is it possible to accomplish this using Angular's "filter" filter, or is this a job for a custom filter?

Comment: I think this can be done only using a custom filter. I searched through the docs but could not find anywhere stating the use of two expression in a filter. So I think you should only use a custom filter for it.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use custom filter for this. Or you could also filter by status array separately from filtering by user name:

```
$scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {user: $scope.filters.user}).filter(function(user) {
    return $scope.filters.status.name.indexOf(user.status.name) > -1;
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/KcP6bLujFnxFPXrVRfUp?p=preview

Comment: This is really great !

Comment: This looks like it'll do the trick for the time being.  Evidently this functionality was fine in previous versions of angular, but on the upgrade to 1.3 it broke.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filterFilter.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think a good approach is to encapsulate all filtering logic about a property into the filter itself, and name that filter by what it does. In this example you have two filters: by user, and by status. It just so happens that currently you are only filtering by *one property* for each of these filters: **name**, but in the future you may have multiple properties to filter by in user and status.

Considering the above I suggest the following two filters for your module:

```
app.filter('byStatus', function() {
  return function(items, filter) {
    var out = [];
    //status.name
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if (filter.name.constructor != Array) {
        if (filter.name == item.status.name) {
          out.push(item);
        }
      } else if (filter.name.indexOf(item.status.name) > -1) {
        out.push(item);
      }
    });
    return out;
  };
});
app.filter('byUser', function() {
  return function(items, value) {
    var out = [];
    //user.name
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if (item.user.name.indexOf(value.name) > -1) {
        out.push(item);
      }
    });
    return out;
  };
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g3ERmycps8Fg6trE1NfN?p=preview

There are two $filter calls but that's fine, I always encourage clarity of code over performance to start with.

Comment: This would be a very good solution, but the data I put in plunkr is only a small sample of the entire dataset.  Ideally I can just filter against any field, rather than create bespoke filters for specific fields.  However, I do like this approach for smaller and more static data.  I'm going to implement this in another area of the application.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Html :-

```
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Status</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: myFilter">
    <td>{{friend.user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.status.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Custom filter :-

```
$scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
    return item.status.name === 'For Review' || item.status.name === 'Approved'; 
};
```